# Conditional formatting of table with angular and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, json, angularjs

How would I go about conditioning below table for when the lastPingedTimeAsString reaches a 5 minute mark and changes the color of the text from green to red, and vice versa.

```
<form name="myform" data-ng-submit="submit()" data-ng-controller="Ctrl" id="submitForm">
        <p data-ng-repeat="beat in beats">
            Station ID: {{ beat.stationID }}
            Uptime: {{ beat.lastPingedAsString | date : 'mediumTime'}}
        </p>
        <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
```

I've looked up several pages on here describing how to use formatting by class, but haven't gotten it to work out correctly.

EDIT: 
To be more clear I need to know how to create the function that determines 5 minutes has elapsed and turn the result from green to red. Sorry for the confusion.

EDIT2: 
Here is the original sample (not formatted at all). I will integrate the new code now.

```
Station ID: default Uptime: Jul 18 2014 2:09PM
```

Comment: I modified the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Let's add a function to our controller scope:

```
$scope.diffMins = function(pingDate) {
  var now = new Date();
  var diffMs = (now-pingDate);
  return Math.round(((diffMs % 86400000) % 3600000) / 60000);
}

<form name="myform" data-ng-submit="submit()" data-ng-controller="Ctrl" id="submitForm">
    <p data-ng-repeat="beat in beats" ng-class="{longtime:diffMins(beat.lastPinged)>=5}">
        Station ID: {{ beat.stationID }}
        Uptime: {{ beat.lastPingedAsString | date : 'mediumTime'}}
    </p>
    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

css:  `.longtime {color: red}`

This assumes you have a `beat.lastPinged` as an javascript date.  You could also put the business logic inside `diffMins` and just return true or false.

`ng-class` works by assinging a class with the name from the left if the right side evaluates as true.

There is also an `ng-style` that does something similar with css style attributes.

Comment: lastPingedasString is a string from lastPinged (another memeber of the database that is DateTime but comes out to a weird format, eg. Date(234505628374550-0400) so this doesn't work for me unfortunately.

Comment: You didn't explain anywhere in your question how someone is to determine 5 minutes.  Is that your question or is it about conditionally applying a class in angular?

Comment: Please make sure and add sample values of `lastPingedAsString` and `lastPinged`

Comment: I added the stationId and lastPingedAsString to the original post, the lastPinged itself returns a variable datetime formatted like so "Date(234505628374550-0400)"

Comment: Is it a string?  What is `lastPingedAsString ` format?  How are these dates being generated?  Can you console.log/json.stringify an instance of beat and add that to your question.

Comment: lastPingedAsString [string]  is pulling from another database value (lastPinged, which is a datetime sql value) I will try to get an instance for you.