# Comparing time logged in file with real time

Tags: html, angularjs

I'm reading uptimes of several applications on different systems. Currently, when the application is launched, it creates an ID with a `pingTime`, and a `pingTimeAsString`. Both are read and shown in html like this (page automatically refreshes every few minutes):

```
 <p>
            System ID: {{ stat.sysID }}
            Uptime: {{ stat.pingTimeAsString | date : 'mediumTime'}}
        </p>
```

Is there a way to compare this `pingTime` or `pingTimeAsString` that is written in a file to the current time + a certain amount of minutes (the duration of how long since the last time the application responded to a ping/sent an update)? That way I can change the listing to display a *ONLINE/OFFLINE* sort of status?

**Update:** How the query looks from reading the RESTService:

```
[{"pingTime":"\/Date(1405706983530-0400)\/","pingTimeAsString":"Jul 21 2014  2:09PM","sysID":"2"}]
```

Comment: Is this a duplicate of  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24831299/conditional-formatting-of-table-with-angular-and-javascript/24831445#comment38629161_24831445

Comment: Where is `pingTime` coming from, and in what format?  Is it something that could be converted into a `Date()` or is it just a ping duration?

Comment: (Incidentally "page automatically refreshes every few minutes" is definitely not how you want to be working with Angular; leave the page alone and make periodic AJAX requests instead.)

Comment: @DanielBeck It's coming from a `query` for a REST service file. Updated post to show how the query looks.

Comment: What does the `a certain amount of minutes` mean? Do you want to get the duration of how long since the last time the application response to a ping?

Comment: @runTarm Yes, if possible. I will clarify this in the post.

Comment: You could do that by using [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/).

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/) library to make the task easier:

```
moment().diff("\/Date(1405706983530-0400)\/") // different from now in milliseconds
```

or if you want the result in other units:

```
moment().diff("\/Date(1405706983530-0400)\/", "minutes");
```

you can even get a human friendly text like:

```
moment([2010, 7, 21]).fromNow(); // 4 years ago
```

Hope this helps.